# How do I recover my wallet with BIP32 ROOT KEY Generated from Iancoleman.io?

Tags: segregated-witness, bip32-hd-wallets, wallet-recovery, cryptography, mnemonic-seed

can I access and withdraw my btc if I have only BIP32 ROOT KEY That was generated from Iancoleman.io

I lost the 12 words..

How can i restore my wallet??

Comment: Yes.. I lost the words.